# make my SOAP web service consumed in local network

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, wsdl, tomcat

I'm using netbeans 7.0 and i create my SOAP webservice and make a java applet consume that webservice and it works fine after i had signed my applet....all that works fine in localhost, but when i tried to consume my web service through local network nothing happened and my webservice failed to consume..I'm sure i miss some thing and that i must configure my web service WSDL to run in local network but actually I don't know the steps and how to do that.

I tried some effort to change the addresses in jax-ws-catalog to my local network address

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

in which 192.168.1.8 is my local network address and 8080 is the port, i don't if I'm acting the right way and hope that it can be done in wizard through netbeans so i can consume my webservice through my local network, i would be glad if any one can give me the steps or some useful links or threads that discuss that issue

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Which interface is your web service listening on.

Enter a "netstat -a" command and see what is LISTENING on port 8080.

If the interface is not 192.168.1.8 or 0.0.0.0 but is 127.0.0.1 then you need to start your webservice on an interface other than your local interface so that it is listened for.

Comment: ok how can I start my webservice with my local interface which in that case is "192.168.1.8" thats is actually my real question :)

Comment: You starting your webservice in netbeans?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with netbeans webservice configuration.  Presumably it is a glassfish server configuration item that should be available somewhere in the configuration for the server.

Comment: Maybe GlassFish also has an admin interface on port 4848 so you can login there with user admin and password adminadmin (unless you changed that) and there you can find out what port GlassFish is listening on (see Configuration -> HTTP Service -> HTTP Listeners).

Comment: awesome but does you have any idea about how to do same using apache tomcate??

Comment: by default tomcat uses all interfaces.  there must be something with the netbeans implementation that controls the local interface only but again am unsure as don't use netbeans

Comment: do you mean that by default tomcat should listen to all interfaces and that I don't need any configuration to make it listen to my interface...did you mean that this is the normal case?

Comment: Yes, this is the normal case, however I do not know how netbeans starts the server so cannot say in yo9ur case